# max_by with multiple return columns

Tags: presto

Presto's documentation says `max_by(x, y)` returns the value of x associated with the maximum value of y over all input values. (https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#max_by)

How can I return multiple columns (not only x) associated with the maximum y? I found that `max_by((x1, x2, x3), y)` works (almost) but it returns a single column with x1, x2, x3 and I don't know how to convert it into multiple columns.

Answer (score 5):

Starting with [Presto 314](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/release/release-314.html), it is now possible to reference [`ROW`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/language/types.html#row) fields using the `[]` operator.

```sql
SELECT r[1], r[2], r[3]
FROM (
   SELECT max_by((x1, x2, x3), y) r
   FROM (...) t(y, x1, x2, x3)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Since Presto 314

As Martin Traverso pointed out, since [Presto 314](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/release/release-314.html) there is a better option, the `[]` subscript operator. See Martin's answer.

#### For older versions, see below

`(x1, x2, x3)` creates a `row` with anonymous fields. Currently, to access individual row fields, [you need to cast the value to a row with named fields](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/language/types.html#row):

```
CAST(row_value AS row(some_field field_type, other_field, field_type, ...))
```

In a query this can be inside `max_by` or outside (doesn't matter).
Example:

```
presto> SELECT r.afield, r.bfield, r.cfield
     -> FROM (
     ->     SELECT max_by(CAST((x1, x2, x3) AS row(afield integer, bfield varchar, cfield double)), y) r
     ->     FROM (VALUES (1, 42, 'a', 13e0), (2, 40, 'b', 77e0)) t(y, x1, x2, x3)
     -> );
 afield | bfield | cfield
--------+--------+--------
     40 | b      |   77.0
(1 row)
```

I understand this is quite verbose. 
There is an issue to make this more convenient: https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/860.